# Call DataGridView User Deleting Row using ContextMenuStip

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I'm facing a problem to call the event `[dgv_clients_UserDeletingRow]` using a `[ContextMenuStrip]`.

It's giving me that error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCanelEventArgs'
```

And here is my code :

```
  Private Sub dgv_clients_UserDeletingRow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles dgv_clients.UserDeletingRow
    deleteLine(e)
End Sub

  Private Sub toolStripItem1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs) Handles toolStripItem1.Click

    If mouseLocation.RowIndex > 0 Then
        dgv_clients.Rows(mouseLocation.RowIndex).Selected = True
        dgv_clients.Rows(mouseLocation.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gray
        DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, args)
    End If

End Sub
Public Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Call deleteLine(e)
End Sub
```

Thank your all

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is your `deleteLine` method.

You are calling it with two different types. In the `Sub dgv_clients_UserDeletingRow` you pass `e as DataGridViewRowCancelEventArg`s and in the `Sub DeleteToolStripMenuItem_Click` you pass `e as EventArgs`. If you haven't overloaded your `deleteLine` method for these two types, the compiler will try to auto-parse the wrong type and it fails.

Comment: Thank your for your help,but i've solved the problem using another method.